# Postgresql Query Performance drop down from 4 secs to 16 minutes just by adding one filter criteria

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization, where-clause

I wrote a simple query that involves 2 views.
I need to find, using self join on "contratti_gas_attivi" (which doesn't contain information on any offer,settled or not), the supplies that doesn't have a settled offer (which I found defined in "offerte_valide_dettaglio" which contains ONLY the informations for all the supplies where an offer is settled) but for which an offers exists for the same end-user supplied till a day before the starting of the new end-user.

So the following code gets me a resutl of almost 50 rows in 4 to 6 seconds (which I dont consider fast but this is not something that should be run frequentely) but I only found the supplies which haven't an offer associated to them but only 3 of those have a previous settled offer.

```
select ovd2.cod_offerta ,ovd2.id_contratto ,ovd2.id_offerta, cga.*,cga2.* from contratti_gas_attivi cga left join  offerte_valide_dettaglio ovd
on ovd.id_contratto = cga.id 
left join contratti_gas_attivi cga2 on cga.cod_pdr =cga2.cod_pdr and cga.data_inizio  = (cga2.data_fine +'1 day'::interval)::date
left join offerte_valide_dettaglio ovd2 on ovd2.id_contratto = cga2.id 
left join crm.customer_offers co on co.id = ovd2.id_offerta 
where cga.tipo_inizio_contratto = 'VOLTURA' and ovd.id_offerta is null;
```

So at the end I just add `and ovd2.cod_offerta is not null` to take out the other 47 rows and the query now takes almost 16 minutes to complete ! Just by adding a filtering clause at the end !
How is that possible ? The query plan get completely screwed...
Before last filter

```
    Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=4472.03..6947.83 rows=1 width=251) (actual time=3052.330..4196.372 rows=54 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=3000.74..4218.60 rows=1 width=112) (actual time=1652.151..1655.099 rows=49 loops=1)
        Join Filter: ((cc2.piva)::text = (cg.piva_cc)::text)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2349
        Filter: (cc2.data_replaced IS NULL)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 3
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=3000.74..4215.59 rows=1 width=94) (actual time=1652.133..1653.982 rows=49 loops=1)
              Join Filter: ((cc.piva)::text = (cg.piva_cliente)::text)
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2349
              Filter: ((cc.data_replaced IS NULL) AND (cc.data_deleted IS NULL) AND (cc.data_deleted IS NULL))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 3
              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=3000.74..4212.58 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=1652.098..1652.268 rows=49 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (ocg.id_contratto = cg.id)
                    Filter: (ocg.id_offerta IS NULL)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 2352
                    ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1457.68..2561.97 rows=40966 width=16) (actual time=1479.736..1501.558 rows=39890 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: (ocg.id_contratto = cg_1.id)
                          ->  Seq Scan on offerte_contratti_gas ocg  (cost=0.00..950.66 rows=40966 width=16) (actual time=0.033..8.184 rows=39890 loops=1)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=1457.66..1457.66 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1479.633..1479.635 rows=36517 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 65536 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1939kB
                                ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..1457.66 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.080..1466.558 rows=36517 loops=1)
                                      Join Filter: ((cc2_1.piva)::text = (cg_1.piva_cc)::text)
                                      Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1747843
                                      Filter: (cc2_1.data_replaced IS NULL)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 4973
                                      ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..1454.65 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.052..743.117 rows=36517 loops=1)
                                            Join Filter: ((cc_1.piva)::text = (cg_1.piva_cliente)::text)
                                            Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1747827
                                            Filter: ((cc_1.data_replaced IS NULL) AND (cc_1.data_deleted IS NULL) AND (cc_1.data_deleted IS NULL))
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 4989
                                            ->  Seq Scan on contratti_gas cg_1  (cost=0.00..1451.64 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.024..13.750 rows=36517 loops=1)
                                                  Filter: ((delated_at IS NULL) AND (replaced_at IS NULL))
                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 47
                                            ->  Seq Scan on controparti_commerciali cc_1  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=45 width=20) (actual time=0.001..0.005 rows=49 loops=36517)
                                      ->  Seq Scan on controparti_commerciali cc2_1  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=45 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.005 rows=49 loops=36517)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1543.05..1543.05 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=145.878..145.878 rows=2104 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 4096 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 253kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on contratti_gas cg  (cost=0.00..1543.05 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=0.035..144.183 rows=2104 loops=1)
                                Filter: ((delated_at IS NULL) AND (replaced_at IS NULL) AND ((tipo_inizio_contratto)::text = 'VOLTURA'::text))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 34460
              ->  Seq Scan on controparti_commerciali cc  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=45 width=38) (actual time=0.002..0.006 rows=49 loops=49)
        ->  Seq Scan on controparti_commerciali cc2  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=45 width=34) (actual time=0.001..0.006 rows=49 loops=49)
  ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=1471.29..2729.21 rows=1 width=139) (actual time=51.523..51.845 rows=1 loops=49)
        Hash Cond: (ocg_1.id_contratto = cg_2.id)
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1457.68..2561.97 rows=40966 width=27) (actual time=28.165..48.297 rows=39890 loops=49)
              Hash Cond: (ocg_1.id_contratto = cg_3.id)
              ->  Seq Scan on offerte_contratti_gas ocg_1  (cost=0.00..950.66 rows=40966 width=27) (actual time=0.002..7.578 rows=39890 loops=49)
              ->  Hash  (cost=1457.66..1457.66 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1379.882..1379.883 rows=36517 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 65536 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1939kB
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..1457.66 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.041..1368.418 rows=36517 loops=1)
                          Join Filter: ((cc2_3.piva)::text = (cg_3.piva_cc)::text)
                          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1747843
                          Filter: (cc2_3.data_replaced IS NULL)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 4973
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..1454.65 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.026..696.145 rows=36517 loops=1)
                                Join Filter: ((cc_3.piva)::text = (cg_3.piva_cliente)::text)
                                Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1747827
                                Filter: ((cc_3.data_replaced IS NULL) AND (cc_3.data_deleted IS NULL) AND (cc_3.data_deleted IS NULL))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 4989
                                ->  Seq Scan on contratti_gas cg_3  (cost=0.00..1451.64 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.013..12.852 rows=36517 loops=1)
                                      Filter: ((delated_at IS NULL) AND (replaced_at IS NULL))
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 47
                                ->  Seq Scan on controparti_commerciali cc_3  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=45 width=20) (actual time=0.001..0.005 rows=49 loops=36517)
                          ->  Seq Scan on controparti_commerciali cc2_3  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=45 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.005 rows=49 loops=36517)
        ->  Hash  (cost=13.60..13.60 rows=1 width=112) (actual time=0.460..0.460 rows=1 loops=49)
              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=10.97..13.60 rows=1 width=112) (actual time=0.439..0.449 rows=1 loops=49)
                    Hash Cond: ((cc2_2.piva)::text = (cg_2.piva_cc)::text)
                    Filter: (cc2_2.data_replaced IS NULL)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                    ->  Seq Scan on controparti_commerciali cc2_2  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=45 width=34) (actual time=0.002..0.006 rows=49 loops=49)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=10.96..10.96 rows=1 width=94) (actual time=0.427..0.427 rows=1 loops=49)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                          ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=8.33..10.96 rows=1 width=94) (actual time=0.405..0.417 rows=1 loops=49)
                                Hash Cond: ((cc_2.piva)::text = (cg_2.piva_cliente)::text)
                                Filter: ((cc_2.data_replaced IS NULL) AND (cc_2.data_deleted IS NULL) AND (cc_2.data_deleted IS NULL))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                                ->  Seq Scan on controparti_commerciali cc_2  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=45 width=38) (actual time=0.003..0.008 rows=49 loops=49)
                                ->  Hash  (cost=8.31..8.31 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=0.391..0.391 rows=1 loops=49)
                                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                      ->  Index Scan using pk_codpdr_datainizio_iserror on contratti_gas cg_2  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=0.382..0.384 rows=1 loops=49)
                                            Index Cond: ((cod_pdr)::text = (cg.cod_pdr)::text)
                                            Filter: ((delated_at IS NULL) AND (replaced_at IS NULL) AND (cg.data_inizio = ((data_fine + '1 day'::interval))::date))
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 2
Planning Time: 5.997 ms
Execution Time: 4196.992 ms
```

After last filter:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=4461.49..6786.31 rows=1 width=251) (actual time=483943.882..1016665.139 rows=43 loops=1)
  Join Filter: (((cg_2.cod_pdr)::text = (cg.cod_pdr)::text) AND (((cg_2.data_fine + '1 day'::interval))::date = cg.data_inizio))
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1954567
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1460.75..2567.69 rows=1 width=139) (actual time=1416.580..5211.218 rows=39890 loops=1)
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=1457.68..2561.97 rows=1 width=139) (actual time=1416.502..1649.064 rows=39890 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (ocg_1.id_contratto = cg_2.id)
              ->  Seq Scan on offerte_contratti_gas ocg_1  (cost=0.00..950.66 rows=40966 width=27) (actual time=0.030..31.748 rows=39890 loops=1)
                    Filter: (cod_offerta IS NOT NULL)
              ->  Hash  (cost=1457.66..1457.66 rows=1 width=112) (actual time=1416.000..1419.044 rows=36517 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 32768 (originally 1024)  Batches: 2 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 3841kB
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..1457.66 rows=1 width=112) (actual time=0.072..1383.415 rows=36517 loops=1)
                          Join Filter: ((cc2_2.piva)::text = (cg_2.piva_cc)::text)
                          Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1747843
                          Filter: (cc2_2.data_replaced IS NULL)
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 4973
                          ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..1454.65 rows=1 width=94) (actual time=0.043..704.608 rows=36517 loops=1)
                                Join Filter: ((cc_2.piva)::text = (cg_2.piva_cliente)::text)
                                Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1747827
                                Filter: ((cc_2.data_replaced IS NULL) AND (cc_2.data_deleted IS NULL) AND (cc_2.data_deleted IS NULL))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 4989
                                ->  Seq Scan on contratti_gas cg_2  (cost=0.00..1451.64 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=0.016..14.948 rows=36517 loops=1)
                                      Filter: ((delated_at IS NULL) AND (replaced_at IS NULL))
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 47
                                ->  Seq Scan on controparti_commerciali cc_2  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=45 width=38) (actual time=0.001..0.005 rows=49 loops=36517)
                          ->  Seq Scan on controparti_commerciali cc2_2  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=45 width=34) (actual time=0.001..0.005 rows=49 loops=36517)
        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=3.08..5.71 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.061..0.073 rows=1 loops=39890)
              Hash Cond: ((cc2_3.piva)::text = (cg_3.piva_cc)::text)
              Filter: (cc2_3.data_replaced IS NULL)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 0
              ->  Seq Scan on controparti_commerciali cc2_3  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=45 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.005 rows=49 loops=39890)
              ->  Hash  (cost=3.06..3.06 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.048..0.048 rows=1 loops=39890)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                    ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=0.44..3.06 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.027..0.036 rows=1 loops=39890)
                          Hash Cond: ((cc_3.piva)::text = (cg_3.piva_cliente)::text)
                          Filter: ((cc_3.data_replaced IS NULL) AND (cc_3.data_deleted IS NULL) AND (cc_3.data_deleted IS NULL))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                          ->  Seq Scan on controparti_commerciali cc_3  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=45 width=20) (actual time=0.001..0.005 rows=49 loops=39890)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=0.42..0.42 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=1 loops=39890)
                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                ->  Index Scan using uq_id on contratti_gas cg_3  (cost=0.29..0.42 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.013..0.013 rows=1 loops=39890)
                                      Index Cond: (id = ocg_1.id_contratto)
                                      Filter: ((delated_at IS NULL) AND (replaced_at IS NULL))
  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=3000.74..4218.60 rows=1 width=112) (actual time=23.552..25.302 rows=49 loops=39890)
        Join Filter: ((cc2.piva)::text = (cg.piva_cc)::text)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2349
        Filter: (cc2.data_replaced IS NULL)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 3
        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=3000.74..4215.59 rows=1 width=94) (actual time=23.533..24.446 rows=49 loops=39890)
              Join Filter: ((cc.piva)::text = (cg.piva_cliente)::text)
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 2349
              Filter: ((cc.data_replaced IS NULL) AND (cc.data_deleted IS NULL) AND (cc.data_deleted IS NULL))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 3
              ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=3000.74..4212.58 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=23.493..23.561 rows=49 loops=39890)
                    Hash Cond: (ocg.id_contratto = cg.id)
                    Filter: (ocg.id_offerta IS NULL)
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 2352
                    ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=1457.68..2561.97 rows=40966 width=16) (actual time=0.034..19.423 rows=39890 loops=39890)
                          Hash Cond: (ocg.id_contratto = cg_1.id)
                          ->  Seq Scan on offerte_contratti_gas ocg  (cost=0.00..950.66 rows=40966 width=16) (actual time=0.002..7.327 rows=39890 loops=39890)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=1457.66..1457.66 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1236.665..1238.748 rows=36517 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 65536 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 1939kB
                                ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..1457.66 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.052..1230.365 rows=36517 loops=1)
                                      Join Filter: ((cc2_1.piva)::text = (cg_1.piva_cc)::text)
                                      Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1747843
                                      Filter: (cc2_1.data_replaced IS NULL)
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 4973
                                      ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..1454.65 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.035..625.434 rows=36517 loops=1)
                                            Join Filter: ((cc_1.piva)::text = (cg_1.piva_cliente)::text)
                                            Rows Removed by Join Filter: 1747827
                                            Filter: ((cc_1.data_replaced IS NULL) AND (cc_1.data_deleted IS NULL) AND (cc_1.data_deleted IS NULL))
                                            Rows Removed by Filter: 4989
                                            ->  Seq Scan on contratti_gas cg_1  (cost=0.00..1451.64 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.012..11.876 rows=36517 loops=1)
                                                  Filter: ((delated_at IS NULL) AND (replaced_at IS NULL))
                                                  Rows Removed by Filter: 47
                                            ->  Seq Scan on controparti_commerciali cc_1  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=45 width=20) (actual time=0.001..0.004 rows=49 loops=36517)
                                      ->  Seq Scan on controparti_commerciali cc2_1  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=45 width=16) (actual time=0.001..0.004 rows=49 loops=36517)
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1543.05..1543.05 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=8.053..8.053 rows=2104 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 4096 (originally 1024)  Batches: 1 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 253kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on contratti_gas cg  (cost=0.00..1543.05 rows=1 width=76) (actual time=0.014..7.482 rows=2104 loops=1)
                                Filter: ((delated_at IS NULL) AND (replaced_at IS NULL) AND ((tipo_inizio_contratto)::text = 'VOLTURA'::text))
                                Rows Removed by Filter: 34460
              ->  Seq Scan on controparti_commerciali cc  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=45 width=38) (actual time=0.001..0.004 rows=49 loops=1954610)
        ->  Seq Scan on controparti_commerciali cc2  (cost=0.00..2.45 rows=45 width=34) (actual time=0.001..0.004 rows=49 loops=1954610)
Planning Time: 7.946 ms
Execution Time: 1016666.928 ms
```

I am not very familiar in reading query plans but I can see that adding the last clause completely ruin the "fast" query plan that was running before! Any advice ?

edit:
Holly molly jjanes that worked wonderfully !
I read that vacuum permanentely delete obsolete deleted/updated tuples and vaccum analyze update the statistic used by the planner. Still I'm a bit confused on why that worked ! The DB is on local and I do only work on it, I did some crud operation on the underlying tables but going from 4 seconds to 16 just because I didn't run the vacuum sounds strange to me! Now the full query only take 187ms !!! Do you have any resource to share beside official docs about vacuum to better understand ?,Many thanks, unfortunately I cannot upvote the answer yet.

Comment: First things first, VACUUM ANALYZE all the involved tables and make sure the problem still exists.

Comment: And if the problem does still exist, edit your post to contain the new plans, gathered with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, and preferably after turning on track_io_timing.

Comment: Do you have an index on offerte_valide_dettaglio with key compound of (cod_offerta, id_offerta, id_contratto) in this strict order ?

Comment: @SQLpro "offerte_valide_dettaglio" (ovd) is a view which is built upon 3 undedrlying tables that can be resumed in contracts (acutal supply data),offers(pool of all the offers submitted, that may not match any contract),valid_offers(which contains only the relations between the contracts id and the offers id that match the contract). I do think I may in future be obliged to enforce some kind of key but I dont think it's necessary at the moment. jjanes suggeastion was the solution I was searching for and as you can see  it dropped down the full query from 16 minutes to under 1 second.

Comment: @Mohican1989 you needs to give us the complete DDL of tables with index. Without that it's impossible to analyse and find the way to have better performances

Comment: @SQLpro the solution provided by jjanes worked wonderfully, as already stated, it resulted in a performance gain of over 16 minutes.

Comment: @jjanes - is it worth adding an answer proper, so the OP can comment underneath and/or vote? (The OP is adding answer commentary to their question post, which we tend to discourage).